# PHP fill array from two foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i have one array and i want to fill from 2 `foreach`

```
preg_match_all('/<div[^>]+class="titr2"[^>]*>\s*<a[^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>\s*<\/div>/si', file_get_contents($handle), $names);


$other = array();

foreach ($names[0] as $value) {

    $pattern = '/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/si';
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);

    $name['A'] = $matches[1];
    $other[]   = $name;
}

preg_match_all('/<\/a><\/div>(.*?)\s*<div[^>]+class="toolz"[^>]*>\s*/si',   file_get_contents($handle), $other);
foreach ($other[1] as $value) {

    $default = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*>(.*)\/>/is', "", $value);
    $default = explode('<br />', $default);

    $name['B'] = $default[0];
    $name['C'] = $default[1];
    $other[]=$name;
}
echo"<pre>";print($other);echo"</pre>";
```

i want to have like this Result :

```
$other = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'A' => 'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
            'B' => 'bbbbbbbbbbbb',
            'C' => 'cccccccccccc'
        ),
    1 => array
        (
            'A' => 'dddddddddddd',
            'B' => 'eeeeeeeeeeee',
            'C' => 'ffffffffffff'
        ),
    2 => array
        (
            'A' => 'gggggggggggg',
            'B' => 'hhhhhhhhhhhh',
            'C' => 'iiiiiiiiiiii'
        )                
);
```

**UPDATED:**

[Current Result:](http://paste.debian.net/80821/)

Comment: What is the current result? Would help if you can add a sample of the file you're working with.

Comment: @AmalMurali this fill bad array with no need rows

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question of what exact results you'Re getting ;) Please just show a var_dump() of what you currently get.

Comment: @JohannesH. i'm edited post and paste result of that on `paste.debian.net`

Comment: That... unicode... stuff... Oo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/<div[^>]+class="titr2"[^>]*>\s*<a[^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>\s*<\/div>/si',  file_get_contents($handle), $names);


$result = array('A'=>array(), 'B'=>array(), 'C'=>array());

foreach ($names[0] as $value) {

    $pattern = '/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/si';
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $match){
        $result['A'][]   = $match;
    }
}

preg_match_all('/<\/a><\/div>(.*?)\s*<div[^>]+class="toolz"[^>]*>\s*/si',   file_get_contents($handle), $other);
foreach ($other[1] as $value) {

    $default = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*>(.*)\/>/is', "", $value);
    $default = explode('<br />', $default);

    $result['B'][] = $default[0];
    $result['C'][] = $default[1];
}
echo"<pre>";print($result);echo"</pre>";
```